# Neo4j: filtering the label collection

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I have a collection of labels, and i'd like to filter them. So i tried:

```
MATCH n:myLabel
WITH filter(t IN labels(n) WHERE t <> 'product') AS notProduct
RETURN notProduct
```

Error:
`Type mismatch: expected Collection but was Boolean` pointing to the start of labels(n)

I notice that i tend to seek the boundaries of what is possible to do with labels, and i feel like i have yet bumped into their limitations once again. Am i abusing labels or should i just write the query differently?

The background idea is that after i filter out a bunch of labels each node will only have 1 label left (the way the application is designed) i can then do an `ORDER BY` on the remaining 1 label. While i can not do an `ORDER BY` on collections of different size.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but that query works for me if I add the missing parentheses for the identifier:Label, i.e. `(n:myLabel)`

Comment: I'm using 2.0.0-M05 .. perhaps i should upgrade o_O

Comment: I did have this issue briefly at http://console.neo4j.org, but it works there as well now: http://console.neo4j.org/r/fzi1xt Maybe you can edit your question with more details if you keep having problems with this.